# How to use filter on show stages and show pipes query in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

```
Show Stages;
```

The above query returns the list of all the stages that are defined in a particular database and the schema in Snowflake.

After finding the stage name the next step is to figure out which pipe is using this stage.

I don't know if it is possible to filter on the `Show Pipes;` query directly so I am running this query, download the result as a `.csv` file then using find in the `.csv` file to figure out which pipe is using the required stage.

Is there a way to filter on the `show pipes` query for a particular stage name in Snowflake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query from `snowflake.account_usage.pipes` view and filter based on database, schema, stage details.

```
select * from snowflake.account_usage.pipes 
where definition like '%<stage name>%' 
and pipe_catalog = '<DB name>' 
and pipe_schema = '<schema name>';
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/pipes